# What is the meaning of bitwise "OR" operator for interfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have seen a bitwise operator used for the Typescript interfaces. Can anyone describe what is its mean here:

```
interface RowGroup {
  __metaData: RowGroupMetaData;
}

interface RowData {
  id: number;
  task: string;
  complete: number;
  priority: string;
  issueType: string;
}

type GridRow = RowGroup | RowData;  //**** THIS LINE
```

Comment: It's not a bitwise OR, it's a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: As far as I remember this is a union.It means that when passing an object of GridRow in a function it can be either a RowGroup or it can be a RowData

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bitwise OR, it's a union type. Read [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) from the documentation.

In plain English, you could say that the `GridRow` type is either a `RowGroup` or a `RowData` type.